# Setting Realm Object property / relation dynamically

Tags: typescript, react-native, reflection, realm

I am using realm in a react native project in typescript, and I would like to assign a relation object to another object dynamically.

For instance, instead of doing `myUserObject.profile = myProfileObject` I would like to do something like that : `myUserObjectTypedAsRealmObject[relationName] = theOtherRealmObject`.

Is it possible to make something dynamic like that ?
I also tried to change type of `relationName` from `string` to `keyof Realm.Object` but that also didn't work.

Edit:

Here is a complete example of what I am trying to do.

```
async getObjectsAndRestoreRelations(
        objectSchema: Realm.ObjectSchema,
        objectsUUIDs: UUID[],
        sourceObject: Realm.Object | null,
        relationship: keyof Realm.Object | null,        
    ) {

        let getOperation = new GetOperation(objectSchema, objectsUUIDs); // Performs GET request
        let objects: Realm.Object[] = await getOperation.run();
        objects.forEach((object: Realm.Object) => {
            if (relationship && sourceObject) {
                let nonNullSourceObject: Realm.Object = sourceObject;
                const relationshipProperty = sourceObject.objectSchema().properties[relationship] as Realm.ObjectSchemaProperty;
                if (relationshipProperty.type === 'object') {
                    nonNullSourceObject[relationship] = object; // Getting a TS 2322 error here, because of the [] operator I guess.
                } else if (relationshipProperty.type === 'array') {
                    nonNullSourceObject[relationship].push(object); // Also an error here because of .push called on the result of the '[]' operation..
                }
            }
        });                
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure the question is clear and the two examples in the question appear unrelated; the first one assigned an object to another objects .profile property and the second appears to be some kind of key: value pair, as would be used in a dictionary? Do you have a more specific and brief coding example?

Comment: I don't know how to explain what I want clearly as I am not native english speaker... I just want to properties/attributes/relationships of a Realm.Object dynamically = without typing its name in my code, the name is in a variable.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the question; perhaps you can include a coding example of what's being attempted or a specific use case. In general *relationships* are somewhat dynamic already in that any object can be directly related to another object. Suppose a `Person` has `List`of `Dog` objects; any `Dog` object can be added or removed from that `List`. If you need a relationship to different object classes, like a `Dog` and `Cat, that can be done as well; in React there's a [mixed](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3389) property type. There's also a dictionary property type as well.

Comment: Ok, but in your example in order to add that dog object to the Person object you will have to write a code like that  `Person.dogs.push(aDogObject)` right ? 
Whereas I want my function to assign object of unknown (well they are Realm.Object) types, example: `aRealmObject.theRelationNameAsVariable.push(aRelatedRealmObject)`
I think that's what we usually call reflection in other languages no ?

In Objective-C, for instance, I would use `[myORMObject setValue: myRelatedORMObject forKey: theRelationNameAsVariable];`

Comment: Understood. Here's the issue; A Realm collection (like a List) is a homogenous container of zero or more instances of one Realm type. However, you can then use the mixed object type (per above) to handle different object types within the List. I think that may fit what you asked - *I want my function to assign object of unknown  types*. See the example [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/model-data/data-types/mixed/#realm-object-models) where the Cat class has a birthDate of type 'mixed' and then in the code in one object it's a String and another case it's a Date.

Comment: Sorry, hard to explain, but my point is not to use "mixed types". 
More context: I am developping a backend <-> mobile synchronization mecanism, to do so my code send GETs to backend API and retrieve objects of a given type (in my example 'User', but I have others and obviously, I don't want to develop a synchronization class for each of them), and then perform GETs for its relations (I read the object schema to get their names) like 'Profile', but once I unserialize the JSON of my 2 objects, I have 2 Realm.Object that I need to connect one to the other.

Comment: I am still not clear - seeing as your question is not getting any other activity, perhaps it's unclear to others. Comments can be helpful but the *question* itself needs to be clear - nobody wants to read through 30 comments to understand the question. So best action here is to think through what you want to do and update the question with details and your attempted code. e.g. provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That may help.

Comment: I edited the question with an example, hope it helps.